# How to do something like unpivot like in oracle sql for the following scenario?

Tags: sql, oracle, unpivot

This is the the table statements, i want to convert the data in something unpivot like using just sql.

```
create table galy(
pro_Date date,
profit number
);
insert into galy values(sysdate-1,30);
insert into galy values(sysdate,20);
insert into galy values(sysdate+1,40);
insert into galy values(sysdate+2,50);
insert into galy values(sysdate+3,70);
commit;
```

Output Needed in a single query (dates having sat and sunday should not be considered)

```
      Date                  d-1                    d                d+1
    01-02-2018(sysdate)      30                    20                40
     ....
     ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pivot/unpivot is not needed to get the data to display in the format you want.  As long as there is only 1 `PRO_DATE` per day, you can use the `LEAD` and `LAG` analytic functions.

#### Query

```
SELECT pro_date,
       LAG (profit) OVER (ORDER BY pro_date)     AS prior_day_profit,
       profit                                    AS current_day_profit,
       LEAD (profit) OVER (ORDER BY pro_date)     AS next_day_profit
  FROM galy;
```

#### Result

```
    PRO_DATE    PRIOR_DAY_PROFIT    CURRENT_DAY_PROFIT    NEXT_DAY_PROFIT
____________ ___________________ _____________________ __________________
04-OCT-20                                           30                 20
05-OCT-20                     30                    20                 40
06-OCT-20                     20                    40                 50
07-OCT-20                     40                    50                 70
08-OCT-20                     50                    70
```

## Update

To exclude weekends, you can simply add a where clause to your query

```
SELECT pro_date,
       LAG (profit) OVER (ORDER BY pro_date)      AS prior_day_profit,
       profit                                     AS current_day_profit,
       LEAD (profit) OVER (ORDER BY pro_date)     AS next_day_profit
  FROM galy
 WHERE TO_CHAR (pro_date, 'DY') NOT IN ('SAT', 'SUN');
```